# how embed if and elif with tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to try and use an if/elif/else condition within a tkinter label widget to check for 1 of three conditions and change the foreground color based on those results...

**condition 1** equipTemp is equal to or greater then hightempset    [foreground color of label widget = 'red']

**condition 2** equipTemp is equal to or less then lowtempset [foreground    color of label widget = 'blue']

**condition 3** equipTemp is less than hightempset and greater than    lowtempset {or, in otherwords conditi
ons #1 and #2 are not met} [foreground color of label widget = 'white']

my one line of code that i'm trying to do this in is:

```
Label4=Label(root, textvariable=equipTemp2, foreground='red' if equipTemp2 => hightempset  elif equipTemp2 =< lowtempset 'blue' else 'white', width=6, justify=LEFT)
```

Comment: assign the color to a variable, update that variable depending on your conditions, call a refresh of the widget.

Comment: Why would like like to do it in one line? whats wrong with having it in other one or two lines?

Comment: i have a number of labels where i want to apply this, i was just curious if it could be done, saw examples of this using if/else but not if/elif/else....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a double if-else statement like:

```
foreground='red' if equipTemp2.get() >= hightempset else 'blue' if equipTemp2.get() <= lowtempset else 'white'
```

Since you are using `equipTemp2` as the textvariable I assumed it's a tkinter `IntVar` or `DoubleVar` so you have to use the `.get()` method. If it's a `StringVar` you'll have to use `int(equipTemp2.get())` or `float(equipTemp2.get())`.

However, I really think doing the assignment like this really hurts readability, and do note that this expression is only evaluated at initiation of the Label, so if `equipTemp2` changes, the color won't change.

---

If you do want to change the color of the label every time the variable changes, you can `trace` the variable and apply the foreground color whenever the variable is changed like so:

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback(*args):
    try:
        Label4.config(foreground='red' if equipTemp2.get() >= hightempset else 'blue' if equipTemp2.get() <= lowtempset else 'white')
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()

equipTemp2 = IntVar()
hightempset = 50
lowtempset = 10

Label4=Label(root, textvariable=equipTemp2, width=6, justify=LEFT)
Label4.pack()
equipTemp2.trace("w", callback)
equipTemp2.set(15)

sb = Spinbox(root, textvariable=equipTemp2, from_=0, to=100)
sb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the try-except block is only because when you type something in the spinbox, the variable becomes `''` for a short while, which an `IntVar` can't handle (it will give a `ValueError`).